# <tbody> does not work with Intro.js

Tags: php, html, intro.js

Why doesn't `<tbody>` works with IntroJs? 
I have tried many ways. It focuses but the `Z=index` has no effect.

Please help anyone

Comment: Could you be more specific about "does not work" - i.e. what are you trying to do?

Comment: Hope u know what intro.js is? if you do, then I am trying to use Intro.js in a table with <tbody>, but it doesnt work